# Solving an equation with random coefficients

Tags: random-variables, stochastic-calculus

I have the following equation:
$$\dfrac{V}{\Sigma}=k*\arcsin{\left(\dfrac{y}{R}\right)}+hy\sqrt{R^2-y^2}$$
where:
$$V=V_0+\epsilon.$$
$$\Sigma=\Sigma_0+\eta$$
$\epsilon$ is a normally distribuited random variable: $\epsilon=\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_0^2)$
and $\eta=\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_1^2)$
I'm stuck on solving the equation respect to the variable $y$.
$k\in\mathbb{R}$,$h\in\mathbb{R}$,$R\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Is problem in randomness? If you assume that $V$ and $\Sigma$ are constants, can you solve this equation?

Comment: @User112358: the standard analytical methods are unable tu solve the equation even in the case in which $V$ and $\Sigma$ are constant

Comment: Randomness of the coefficients is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I think randomness is important in order to have an idea about the spectral behaviour of $y$

Comment: No, this plays strictly no role in the resolution of the equation, which is the topic of your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing unnecessary constants, the equation can be rewritten

$$\alpha\arcsin z+\beta z\sqrt{1-z^2}=1.$$ (Notice that there are only two independent coefficients.)

As the unknown appears both inside and outside a transcendental function, there is no closed-form solution and you must resort to numerical methods.

Here is what the curves look like for a few values of the coefficients. Depending on these, there can be one or two real solutions (intersect with horizontals).

[image]

Fortunately, when computing the zeroes of the derivative, the $\arcsin$ disappears and you end-up with a simple quadratic expression. Hence you can easily discuss and isolate the roots.